# This is the question about integration.

Tags: integration

[image: This is the problem.]

[image: This is my solution.]

My idea is to use substitute integration.

Since there is square root of (1-x^2), I made x = cos^2t, and then eliminated square root.

I don't know why my answer is wrong.

I already conducted error check three times, but there are still no error.

Please let me know if there is problem on my solution, or if there is better solution,

tell me. Thanks

Comment: That picture is from a different question.

Comment: 2/15 is the correct answer if you don't multiply by that 14 in front.

Comment: Thank you ! I found the mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ does suggest a trig substitution, the positive power of $x$ on the outside makes it easier to do this integral by parts:

Let $u=x^2$ and $dv = x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
u=x^2 & v = - \frac{1}{3}(1-x^2)^{3/2} \\
du = 2x\,dx & dv = x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx
\end{array}
$$Then 
$$
\int_0^1 u\, dv = \left.uv\right|_0^1 - \int_0^1 v\,du
$$
$$
\int_0^1 x^2 x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx =-\frac{1}{3} \left.x^2(1-x^2)^{3/2}\right|_0^1 +\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{3/2}2x\,dx
$$
The $uv$ term vanishes because $x^2$ vanishes at 0 and $(1-x^2)^{3/2}$ vanishes at 1. The remaining integral is easy because we have a factor of $2x$ multiplying our power of $(1-x^2)$.
$$
\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{3/2}2x\,dx = -\frac{1}{3}\left.\frac{2}{5}(1-x^2)^{5/2}\right|_0^1=\frac{2}{15}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation ! I  understood :D

Answer (score 0):

$$14\int_0^1x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=14\int_0^1x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}xdx=14\int_1^0(1-t)\sqrt t\frac{dt}{-2}=$$
$$=7\int_0^1(1-t)\sqrt tdt=7\int_0^1t^{1/2}dt-7\int_0^1t^{3/2}dt=...$$
$1-x^2=t,-2xdx=dt,xdx=\frac{dt}{-2},x^2=1-t$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :D .. I understood !